# Send extra parameter to django routes in include

Tags: python, django

It is some way to send extra parameters to all routes in a include ?

I'm doing this and works:

```
path('<str:lang>/auth/', include('apps.auth.routes'), {'lang': 'en'}, name='auth_routes')
```

but I want to send lang string on that parameter, something like this:

```
path('<str:lang>/auth/', include('apps.auth.routes'), {'lang': lang}, name='auth_routes')
```

What do I have to do to fix that ?

Comment: Just remove the `{'lang': lang}` part.

Answer (score 1):

It will send it to all views that are included, so you can implement this with:

```
path('<str:lang>/auth/', include('apps.auth.routes'), name='auth_routes')
```

Comment: You are correct, I had an error in my code. Thanks!